# Iterable union of two vectors

Tags: c++, boost, stl, iterator, boost-iterators

I have two arrays, as follows:

```
std::array<int,6> A,B;
//Fill A with random data
//File B with random data
```

For whatever reason, I'd like some kind of container object which lets me access both of the vectors individually, but also to iterate over their union, allowing for actions such as follows:

```
union_container uc(A,B);
for(unioned::iterator i=uc.begin();i!=uc.end();++i)
  *i+=1;
uc.first()[2]=4;
uc.second()[4]=5;
```

I could code this unioned class myself, but perhaps there is already a library which allows this?

Comment: Maybe [boost::zip_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html)?

Comment: I'd be willing to give it a try, @yhager, but how are you suggesting it be used?

Comment: did my answer work for you? if not, please help me improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Boost zip iterators](http://www.gps.caltech.edu/~walter/arx/ArX-2.2.4/src/boost/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html) is one way to do this.

```
#include <array>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>

template<typename T>
using ZipIt = boost::zip_iterator< boost::tuple<T*, T*> >;

template<typename T>
using ZipRef = decltype(*ZipIt<T>());

template<typename T>
void operator+=(ZipRef<T> z, T const& v)
{
    z.template get<0>() += v;
    z.template get<1>() += v;    
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 6> a = { 1, 3, 5, 7,  9, 11 };
    std::array<int, 6> b = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 };

    std::for_each(
        boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(std::begin(a), std::begin(b))), 
        boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(std::end(a), std::end(b))), 
        [](ZipRef<int> z){ z += 1; }
    );

    std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ",")); std::cout << "\n";
    std::copy(std::begin(b), std::end(b), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ",")); std::cout << "\n";

    a[2] = 4;
    b[4] = 5;
}
```

Online [output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d4c8299059e0c70f60174c6849065e97-964d511b763697b11567dd233d45657b).

Note that the code above is not as general as I've would liked, since the jump to variadic templates and general iterator types proved a bit hairy (left as an exercise!) This has mainly to do with the fact that `boost::zip_iterator` uses some tricky internal facades around `boost::tuple`. For this reason I also used `decltype` in the template alias for `ZipRef` to avoid having to write such nasty types inside the `std::for_each` lambda expression.